# configure claims authentication in Sharepoint Which has configurd in 2 different servers

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

am trying to implement claims based authentication in sharepoint which is configured in 2 different servers.

previously it was in one server.. its worked fine with custom STS provider.

now i followed same steps to configure custom STS in share point in server 1..

but token is not accepting by sharepoint  its again redirecting to custom STS provider

sharepoint.com -> redirecting to CustomSts.com (authentication done) posting token to sharepoint.com but sharepoint.com is again redirecting to CustomSts.com (as already authenticated ) its redirecting to sharepoint.com. cycle repeats that should not be happen

is there any solution for this

**Sharepoint 2013**

Comment: Are you using Kerberos for this?

Comment: no.. Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)

Comment: Can you add the code for the authentication part in Sharepoint? And just to clarify, the user is alreadu authenticated for the second redirect to CustomSts?

Comment: WIF is a framework helps you develop claims related components. You still need to use an authentication protocol such as Kerberos or NTLM. If you are using SharePoint with claims and NTLM it worked on one machine just fine. When you add another machine to the mix, you might have to change from NTLM to Kerberos and configure delegation and Service Principal Names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue got fixed by maintaining same time in 2 sharepoint servers and CustomSTS server.

Actually one of the sharepoint server time is different from customSTS server time so, sharepoint application is treating that incoming claims are expired after login, so its again redirecting to CustomSTS server for live claims.
We maintained the same time between the servers, this fixes our issue.

Thanks friends for helping.